# Standardising Kernel Density Plot's Width & Legend Scale

Tags: r, plot, kernel-density

I have the following 4 kernel density plots, but would like the legend scale as well as the plot width/height to be the same across all 4 for comparison.

My codes are:

```
kde_pipit_2014_bw <- density(Pipit_ppp_2016, sigma=4.18, edge=TRUE, kernel="gaussian") 
kde_pipit_2015_bw <- density(Pipit_ppp_2016, sigma=4.18, edge=TRUE, kernel="gaussian") 
kde_pipit_2016_bw <- density(Pipit_ppp_2016, sigma=4.18, edge=TRUE, kernel="gaussian") 
kde_pipit_2016_bw <- density(Pipit_ppp_2016, sigma=4.18, edge=TRUE, kernel="gaussian")

par(mfrow=c(2,2),cex=0.7, mai=c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2))
plot(kde_pipit_2014_bw) 
plot(kde_pipit_2015_bw) 
plot(kde_pipit_2016_bw) 
plot(kde_pipit_2017_bw)
```

Below is an image of the plots. Is there any way I can scale it to the same size for comparison?

[image]

Comment: welcome. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   Please provide minimal reproducible data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: add an image *into* the question and ideally do not link to another site (see my edit)

Comment: I would probably use [tag:ggplot2] (also because I dont know so much baseR graphics). and define my axis limits.. Saying this - it must be surely possible to define the  axis limits in baseR too.

Comment: BUT why does your code give different results? I have the impression that you are having a copy paste error there maybe?? Because you are always using the same data in your plot calls. If those are different data sets - maybe merge them , put them into a long format, and use **facetting**

Comment: @Tjebo, new users can't embed images. They just get uploaded to imgur. You can edit to embed.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided sample data, so I am using `mtcars`.
This is a way with [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2)
The trick is, as mentioned in the comment, to merge your possibly existing several dataframes from each year, into one data frame, into ideally a long format with a column containing the 'year' information.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 

  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green",high="red")+
  facet_grid(~cyl)  ## you can replace this with your year

#the colors are just examples, I did not try to reproduce exactly your color scale
```

[image]